# Coordinates system using char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, coordinates

```
char boardCoordinates[15]; 
   void setupBoardCoordinates(char boardCoordinates[]) 
{
    boardCoordinates[0] = "0,0";
    boardCoordinates[1] = "0,1";
    boardCoordinates[2] = "1,1";
    boardCoordinates[3] = "0,2";
    boardCoordinates[4] = "1,2";
    boardCoordinates[5] = "2,2";
    boardCoordinates[6] = "0,3";
    boardCoordinates[7] = "1,3";
    boardCoordinates[8] = "2,3";
    boardCoordinates[9] = "3,3";
    boardCoordinates[10] = "0,4";
    boardCoordinates[11] = "1,4";
    boardCoordinates[12] = "2,4";
    boardCoordinates[13] = "3,4";
    boardCoordinates[14] = "4,4";
}

int getCoordinateX(const char boardCoordinates[], int number) 
{
    char coordinates[] = boardCoordinates[number];
    char xValue = coordinates[2];

    return (int) xValue;
}
```

So I'm trying to setup a coordinates system where each boardCoordinate[number] acts as a coordinate to a "number", the one entered as the index value for boardCoordinate.

What I've tried to do is setup a system where each boardCoordinate would have a char array (string) that contains the coordinates and can be extracted using the getCoordinateX value that returns the X coordinate for example.

It doesn't seem to be working because of some pointer errors in the geCoordinateX function.

Any ideas how I would go about fixing this issue so I can retrieve the X coordinate? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don'tr spam tags! C++ is a different language.

Comment: you'd find it easier and more maintainable to do this with structs

Comment: Preferably trying to avoid Structs and do it without them @ChrisTurner :)

Comment: Please read [ask]. You are supposed to show compilable code, or if you have a syntactic question show the problematic line and the compilation error message. But one error per line is really too much...

Comment: "Preferably trying to avoid Structs and do it without them" - So you refuse using the language feature meant for this for some arcane reason? Sorry, but stack overflow is dedicated to **enhance** code quality, not degrade it.

Comment: @TMartin: That is not valid C code anyway. There is no position `1` or `0`; the code is plain wrong.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this but you can subtract the correct value from the char to get the right number like if you cast  `char '0'` to `int` then it'll be a number, specifically 48 so if you do `((int) '0')-48` you'll get back a number

Comment: @Olaf Avoiding Structs solely for learning purposes.  :)

Comment: @Olaf thanks you're right. I just skimmed it and figured it was an index error.

Comment: I wonder what you can learn from not using a feature..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you said:

> Do you also have an implementation without Structs? I'm trying to avoid using Structs for learning purposes. And also thank you for the well explained post!

You can use an int to store the coordinates. If the coordinate values are limited to 0-9, you can use the number `x*10 + y` to represent them. If the coordinate values are limited to 0-99, you can use the number `x*100 + y` to represent them.

E.g. assuming `x*10 + y`:

```
int boardCoordinates[15]; 

void setupBoardCoordinates(char boardCoordinates[]) 
{
   boardCoordinates[0] = 0;
   boardCoordinates[1] = 1;
   boardCoordinates[2] = 11;
   boardCoordinates[3] = 2;
   boardCoordinates[4] = 12;
   boardCoordinates[5] = 22;
   boardCoordinates[6] = 3;
   boardCoordinates[7] = 13;
   boardCoordinates[8] = 23;
   boardCoordinates[9] = 33;
   boardCoordinates[10] = 4;
   boardCoordinates[11] = 14;
   boardCoordinates[12] = 24;
   boardCoordinates[13] = 34;
   boardCoordinates[14] = 44;
}

int getCoordinateX(const char boardCoordinates[], int number) 
{
   return boardCoordinates[number]/10;
}

int getCoordinateY(const char boardCoordinates[], int number) 
{
   return boardCoordinates[number]%10;
}
```

You can refine it if you need to use `x*100 + y`.

Answer (score 4):

There are some problems with your approach,

1. You don't need the coordinates to be strings at all, just create a structure

   ```
   struct coordinate {
       int x;
       int y;
   };
   ```
2. A `char *` pointer is not of type `char`, you are apparently storing pointers to string literals with type `const char *` to an array of type `char[]` with elements of type `char`, it might compile because `char` is an integer type but it's incorrect because the conversion does not guarantee a defined behavior, in fact it's undefined as specified in the c standard. It should however, generate some warnings about the conversions.

If you use the `struct coordinate`, you can write

```
const struct coordinate *
get_coordinate_x(int index)
{
    static const struct coordinate board_coordinates[15] = {
        {0, 0}, {0, 1}, ..., {4, 4}
    };
    return &board_coordinates[index];
}
```

or the equivalent, just remeber that you can't returna pointer to a local variable because you will cause undefined behavior, that's why I've used `static`, you can also pass the array like your example.

Comment: Thank you for this! :) Do you also have an implementation without Structs? I'm trying to avoid using Structs for learning purposes. And also thank you for the well explained post!

Comment: If you avoid structs for this and use a string for the coordinates you will get in trouble and have more difficulties learning the language than you think. Instead, avoid the coordinate system if you don't want to use structs yet. Structures are a very important part of the c language, you can't write anything interesting without them, and they are not difficult to understand or use at all. If I was learning c now, I would avoid pointers and strings, but not structs.

Comment: @Imdad also note that others suggest this solution too, it's because they are experimented c programmers that understand why this is the simplest and more straight forward solution.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is `struct` as already explained in another answer (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43259364/4386427).

But you commented:

> Preferably trying to avoid Structs and do it without them

Okay, if you really want to save the coordinates as comma separated string, i.e. `"x,y"`, it can of cause be done but there are several issues with your current code.

First

```
char boardCoordinates[15];
```

This is not an array of 15 strings. It's a single string with room for 15 chars including the zero termination. To make 15 strings of length upto 3, you'll need:

```
char boardCoordinates[15][4]; // Notice 4 to make room for string termination
```

The next problem is the assignment. Instead of

```
boardCoordinates[0] = "0,0";
```

you'll need

```
strcpy(boardCoordinates[0], "0,0");
```

or you could initialize the variable like:

```
char boardCoordinates[15][4] = {"0,0", "0,1", "1,1", ...... };
```

For the `getCoordinateX` function you could do something like:

```
int getCoordinateX(const char boardCoordinates[][4], int number) 
{
    int xValue = boardCoordinates[number][0] - '0';

    return xValue;
}
```

But **notice** that will **only** work for coordinates between 0 and 9. If coordinates can be 10 or higher (or negative), you'll need more code to extract `x` and `y` correctly (and more space than 4 for each string).

So here is a little sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getCoordinateX(const char boardCoordinates[][4], int number) 
{
    int xValue = boardCoordinates[number][0] - '0';
    return xValue;
}

int getCoordinateY(const char boardCoordinates[][4], int number) 
{
    int yValue = boardCoordinates[number][2] - '0';
    return yValue;
}

int main(void) {
    char boardCoordinates[2][4] = {"1,2", "3,4"};

    printf("x[0]=%d\n", getCoordinateX(boardCoordinates, 0));
    printf("y[0]=%d\n", getCoordinateY(boardCoordinates, 0));
    printf("x[1]=%d\n", getCoordinateX(boardCoordinates, 1));
    printf("y[1]=%d\n", getCoordinateY(boardCoordinates, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x[0]=1
y[0]=2
x[1]=3
y[1]=4
```

**Just to repeat:** It can be done using text strings but the best way is `struct` as explained by @Iharob Al Asimi

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an array of int arrays like so:

```
int coords[15][2] = {{0,0},{0,1},{1,1},{0,2},{1,2},{2,2},{0,3},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{0,4},{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4}};
```

Access it like `coords[3][1]` this would return `2` from `{0,2}`

If you would like to print out "x,y" you can always do:

```
std::cout << coords[i][0] << ',' << coords[i][1] << std::endl;
```